# Meaning of "mentire sapendo di mentire"

Tags: meaning

I have read the following sentence in an Italian language learning tool:

> Menti sapendo di mentire.

I think that means "You lie knowingly"? Could that construction be used with other verbs as a synonym of "intenzionalmente" (e.g., "Ferisce i suoi sentimenti sapendo de ferire")?

Comment: _Di ferire_, not *_de ferire_. Moreover, since _ferire_ is a transitive verb, if one were to use that sentence, they'd probably say _Ferisce i suoi sentimenti sapendo di ferirli_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your translation is perfectly correct. The sentence means exactly *"You lie and you know that"*.

Of course you can use the same construct with other verbs, albeit it is less common (myself, I've never heard *"Ferisce sapendo di ferire"* but it is totally valid).

The sentence is equivalent of

> Menti e lo fai di proposito

or

> Menti e lo fai apposta

But the original sentence uses the repetition of the verb *Mentire* at the beginning and the end of the phrase for rethorical purposes to emphasize the concept; if I am not wrong this figure of speech is an [Epanalepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanalepsis).